# What is different in this claim from US7160405B2 Marcel Aeschlimann?

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [WO2016054751A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2016054751A1)

What, in this claim is different from the following? (same applicant...extending life of the patent?)
Integral joining
Grant US7160405B2 Marcel Aeschlimann Woodwelding Ag
Priority 1999-06-18 • Filing 2004-11-19 • Grant 2007-01-09 • Publication 2007-01-09
A method for joining bodies by melting down a joining element. The joining element acts on a surface of one of the bodies and penetrates the surface as a result of a directed force. Once in a penetrated condition, a mechanical excitation …

Comment: You don't include a link to the US patent but you do realize that a international application can have the same claims as a US patent.

Answer (score 1):

I've only looked briefly at the cited application and patent. In the patent it seems that a part pierces another part and then mechanical excitation is applied to melt a thermoplastic which provides the bond. In the application, it seems that the two pieces have corresponding features (like a tongue and groove). The cited patent is clearly relevant as prior art, but I can't say whether it precludes the application from becoming a patent.